# Organizing manual with different versions in MySQL database

Tags: mysql

I'm currently creating webpage with a mysql database where our user manual will be displayed for customers.

The problem I'm having is with version control, mostly querying. I will be storing "sections" of the manual as rows in the database with a version number as a column for each section. So when a new version of our software comes out, instead of redoing the whole manual, we can just change sections by adding a new row (section) in the database with the new version number and add the same "section_id" as the one we're changing so it will know which section it is replacing. Doing it this way will allow users to search previous versions of the user manual as well.

I read on another stack overflow post that it's better to store versions in 3 columns in the database (major, minor, build/patch). If this is the way to go, how would I query the database to show only the latest "version" rows, or the most recent previous ones, if some sections don't have current versions. Basically, I still need to show sections that haven't been changed in the latest version.

If there is an easier way to organize and query the database, I would also like to know.

Here's a visual example of the database (the position column is technically in a different table with a section_id index, but this is just for the example:

[image: mysql table]

Added image of this table above, in case it doesn't display correctly.

```
id | section_name | section_id | position | v_major | v_minor | v_build
------------------------------------------------------------------------
1    section        1            1          2         2         0035
2    section        4            4          2         1         0027
3    section        3            2          2         1         0027
4    section        2            3          2         2         0035
5    section        3            2          2         2         0035
6    section        1            1          2         1         0027
```

**The query should skip id #3 and #6 as there is a new version to replace that section_id.**

Keep in mind that I would need a way to query older version as well in a similar way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no universal rule for how to store versions - as usual, "it depends", on your specific needs. There is nothing wrong with a single column named "version", if that works for your environment.

But regardless of how many fields you use for versioning, there is usually a desire to know the "current" version. Here are three examples of common ways of doing that:

1. Sort by the "version number" (one column or all columns concatenated together), where the highest "number" is considered current (so "006.000.0001" is higher than "005.999.1234", for example)
2. Have a timestamp associated with every version (i.e. it's "effective date"), and then sort on this timestamp, considering the most recent date to be the current one.
3. But what if you have a brand new version that's not yet "current"?  You can also use a dedicated flag column named something like IS_CURRENT, and explicitly set the value of this flag to "TRUE" or whatever value you want to indicate which version is current. Of course, you have to make sure that one and only one version gets marked current at a time, but that shouldn't be too difficult.

Using any of these methods allows you to 1) identify the current version, and 2) still have available all the previous versions if/when they are needed.

Comment: Wow. Thanks so much for the fast answer! The timestamp is a great idea I would have never thought about using. I was thinking of having a table of "version" and using a column of timestamp to join both tables. Does that make sense?

Comment: If you have one "thing" (User Manual, etc.) with multiple versions, and at least some of the attributes need to stay consistent across versions (for example, the Name, Description, POC, whatever) then you would probably want only one instance of the thing itself, and multiple versions tracked in a separate table (1-to-many).  But if the attributes might change with every version, AND you want to preserve the historical values, then you can keep it all in one table.

Comment: Thanks so much for your help SlimsGhost! Appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

The only reason to have multiple version columns is if the sort order would be inaccurate with a single string. This is often the case, though, with 2.10.1 being newer than 2.2.50 in fact, but not lexically. I think this is what you are after:

```
SELECT 
  CAST(SUBSTRING_INDEX(GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT id ORDER BY v_major DESC, v_minor DESC, v_build DESC), ',', 1) AS UNSIGNED) 
FROM tbl
GROUP BY section_name, section_id
```

It gets the most recent id for each (section_name, section_id) pair. If you need more columns, you can use this as a subquery. I would use something like this to recompute which rows are current if you need to cache it for speed (reduces human error). If you have a target version in mind, you can even guard it in a WHERE clause:

```
WHERE v_major <= 2 AND IF(v_major = 2, v_minor <= 1, 1) AND IF(v_major = 2 AND v_minor = 1, v_build <= 27, 1)
```

Comment: You're right, the main issue with a single version column is it's unsortable. You're answer is what I was looking for, but SlimsGhost made a good point above of possibly associating a timestamp with each version number for sorting purposes. If that doesn't work properly, then you're solution perfect. Thanks for taking the time to figure this out. Much appreciated!

Comment: Your welcome... I use that pattern so much, I have it saved as a snippet.